# GC spinning all the time despite much free heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have an application running with `-mx7000m`. I can see it's allocated 5.5 GB heap. Yet for some reasons it's GCing constantly, and that being CMS it turns out to be quite CPU intensive. So, it has 5.5 GB heap already allocated, but somehow it's spending all the CPU time trying to keep the used heap as small as possible, which is around 2 GB - and the other 3.5G are allocated by JVM but unused.

I have a few servers with the exact same configuration and 2 out of 5 are behaving this way. What could explain it?

It's Java 6, the flags are: `-server -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Duser.timezone=America/Chicago -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/whatever -Xloggc:logs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -mx7000m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

Comment: Regardless of the size of heap, the amount of time that GC runs will be roughly proportional to the rate at which your app creates objects, and only mildly affected by heap size.

Answer (score 0):

The default threshold for triggering a CMS GC is 70% full (in Java 6).  A rule of thumb is that the heap size should be about 2.5x the heap used after a full GC (but your use case is likely to be different)

So in your case, say you have

```
- 2.5 GB of young generation space
- 3 GB of tenured space.
```

When you tenured space reached 70% or ~2.1GB, it will start cleaning up the region.

The setting involved is the `-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70`

However, if you want to reduce the impact GC, the simplest thing to do is to create less garbage. i.e. use a memory profiler and ensure you allocation rate is as low as possible.  Your system will run very different if you are creating as much garbage as the CPUs can handle to say 100 MB/s or 1 MB/s or less.

The reason you might have different servers running differently as the relative sizes of the region might be different, say you have 0.5 young and 5.0 GB tenured, you shouldn't be seeing this.  The difference could be purely down to how busy the machine was when you started the process or what it did since then.

Comment: Looks like I some reading ahead. Determine generation occupancy, learn more about CMS and tune it. Creating less garbage is hard, you can tell it's a fairly big app. I know it depends, but if it was an issue with young gen overflow, would you recommend tuning towards larger space for younger fractions or smaller? Larger initiating occupancy or smaller?

Comment: @KonradGarus With a profiler, it doesn't matter how complex your application is, you just start with the top three worst offenders and work down.  I will bet you that in your top ten is something which isn't needed any more ;)

Comment: @KonradGarus I prefer larger Eden sizes (up to 24 GB) and small tenured space and store most of your data off heap ( 50 GB to 10 TB )  There is lots of options, but when I start consulting on a new application, the easiest is to start with the memory profiler.  The largest JVM I have run using off heap was 100 TB (only as a test ;)